# Ошибка NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Bboard - объявление, rubric - рубрика. Каждое объявление принадлежит какой либо рубрике. Мне нужно, что url адрес конкретного объявления имел вид: str:rubric_name/int:bboard_id. 
Ошибку не выдает при этом коде. Т.е когда rubric_name и bboard_id не находятся в url одновременно.

```py
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='bboard_index'),
    path('add_Bb', views.BbCreateView.as_view(), name='add_Bb'),
    path('<str:rubric_name>', views.by_rubric, name='by_rubric'),
    path('page/<int:bboard_id>/add_com', views.new_comment, name='add_com'),
    path('page/<int:bboard_id>', views.Bboard_page, name='bboard_page'),
]
```

Но при добавлении rubric_name, сразу выдает ошибку NoReverseMatch, даже если мы находимся в корне bboard/ без аргументов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='bboard_index'),
    path('add_Bb', views.BbCreateView.as_view(), name='add_Bb'),
    path('<str:rubric_name>/<int:bboard_id>/add_com', views.new_comment, name='add_com'),
    path('<str:rubric_name>/<int:bboard_id>', views.Bboard_page, name='bboard_page'), 
    path('<str:rubric_name>', views.by_rubric, name='by_rubric'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ты на какую ссылку переходил, когда `NoReverseMatch` вылезал? Ссылка должна быть вида `http://localhost:8000/rubric/13` или `http://localhost:8000/rubric/13/add_com`. Кроме того в функции во `views.py` или же в классе должны быть соответствующие аргументы.

Comment: Ошибку выдает при переходе на любую страницу, кроме админки или рубрик в которых нет объявлений (п-р: http://localhost:8000/bboard/ПК   - где ПК новая рубрика). В посте я переходил на bboard/ что должно соответсвовать ' ' и открывать bboard_index. Но даже это не срабатывает.

Comment: Так же, если бы проблема была с аргументами, в Traceback была бы ошибка связанная с аргументами.

Comment: У тебя эти url прописаны в глобальном файле urls.py, или в файле приложения?

Comment: в файле приложения - bboard

Comment: если ты переходишь на bboard/add_Bb, там нормально или тоже ошибка?

Comment: Форма работает исправно. Сейчас проверил http://localhost:8000/bboard/Недвижимость/2/add_com -- работает. НО http://localhost:8000/bboard/Недвижимость/2/ -- та же ошибка

Comment: Возможно проблема в templates. Сейчас проверю, если пофиксю отпишу.

Comment: А если просто вписать url в браузере, ошибка будет? Да и что у тебя в шаблонах

Comment: До меня доперло. Ошибка скорее всего в шаблонах. Как у тебя там url прописан и добавил ли ты рубрику?

Comment: Ну го https://vk.com/lleballex